# Resharper "Debug Current Session" option or Keyboard Shortcut mapping

Tags: visual-studio-2008, unit-testing, resharper

Is there any "Debug Current Session" option within Resharper that works the same as "Run Current Session" or "Debug Selected Tests".

I want to create a keyboard shortcut that will debug the current Unit Test Session (or selected tests) regardless of what file currently has focus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems [build 5.1.1735](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+5.1.1+Bugfix+Builds) has ReSharper_UnitTestSession_DebugProcess command. Unfortunately it seems not to work unless the focus is on a test fixture or Unit Test Sessions window. Easy fix is to create a macro and assign to keyboard shortcut, e.g.:

```
    DTE.Windows.Item("{B2BC9916-E3E6-43A8-AD5F-3BDB95F53DB5}").Activate() 'Unit Test Sessions - Session #1
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("ReSharper_UnitTestSession_DebugProcess")
```

Comment: Yep, the DebugProcess isn't exactly what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK currently there isn't and IIRC it's on the list, but I'll make sure.